# Twilio Phone Tree not working on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, flask, twilio, pythonanywhere

I have been trying to create a phone tree for my business.  I am really not a developer or coder.  I am a small business owner looking to implement some basic, cost effective automations and have found python to be pretty good for that.  Most things I've been able to resolve myself by reading and watching tutorials, but I am really struggling with this one.  I developed a phone tree using a twilio tutorial, an ngrok tunnel, and a flask server on my computer.  I got it all working flawlessly in just a couple hours.  Very happy with that part.  Then I tried to host it on pythonanywhere and I've had absolutely no success.  I have gotten various types of errors, but most recently, I don't even see any error in the log.  Here is my main code for the phone tree

```
from flask import Flask, request, session
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse, Say, Gather, Dial, Record, Enqueue
import os
from twilio.rest import Client
import time

account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
twilio_number = os.environ['TWILIO_NUMBER']
RCL_number = '+-------'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'top-secret!'

def enter_greeting():
    return Say('Welcome to MY BUSINESS.')


def enter_menu():
    gather = Gather(action_on_empty_result=True, num_digits=1)
    gather.say('Listen to the following menu options. '
               'For a quote for services, press one. '
               'For a list of services and our business hours, press two. '
               'To repeat these options, press nine. '
               'To speak with somebody, press zero. ')
    return gather

def exit_menu():
    transitions = {
        '1': 'sales',
        '2': 'hours',
        '9': 'menu',
        '0': 'reception',
    }
    selection = request.form.get('Digits')
    if selection in transitions:
        return enter_state(transitions[selection])
    else:
        return enter_state('error')


def transcribe():
    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
    transcription = client.transcriptions.list(limit=1)
    time.sleep(30)
    sid = transcription[0].sid
    t = client.transcriptions(sid).fetch()
    m = client.messages \
        .create(
            body = str(t.transcription_text),
            from_=twilio_number,
            to=RCL_number
        )
    print(m.sid)

def enter_sales():
    return [
        Say('All our sales representatives are currently busy, please leave us a detailed message.'),
        Record(transcribe=True),
    ]

def enter_support():
    return [
        Say('You are being transferred to the support line. A representative will be with you shortly.'),
        Enqueue('support'),
    ]

def enter_hours():
    gather = Gather(action_on_empty_result=True, num_digits=1)
    gather.say('We are open Mondays through Fridays from 8 AM to 5 PM.')
    gather.pause()
    gather.say('Press 1 to repeat this message or any other key to go back to the menu.')
    return gather

def exit_hours():
    selection = request.form.get('Digits')
    if selection == '1':
        return enter_state('hours')
    else:
        return enter_state('menu')

def enter_reception():
    return Dial('+-------')

def enter_error():
    return Say('The option that you selected is invalid.')

IVR = {
    'greeting': (enter_greeting, 'menu'),
    'menu': (enter_menu, exit_menu),
    'sales': (enter_sales, transcribe),
    'support': (enter_support, None),
    'hours': (enter_hours, exit_hours),
    'reception': (enter_reception, None),
    'error': (enter_error, 'menu'),
}


def enter_state(state):
    response = VoiceResponse()
    while True:
        # access the requested state
        session['ivr_state'] = state
        enter_handler, exit_handler = IVR[state]

        # invoke the "enter" action for the state
        actions = enter_handler()
        if isinstance(actions, list):
            for action in actions:
                response.append(action)
        else:
            response.append(actions)

        # if the state has a string exit handler, transition to that state
        # and continue building a response
        if isinstance(exit_handler, str):
            state = exit_handler
        else:
            # let the called hear the response for this state and provide input
            return response


def exit_state(state):
    _, exit_handler = IVR[state]
    return exit_handler()


@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def ivr_webhook():
    state = session.get('ivr_state')
    if state is None:
        # this is a new call
        return str(enter_state('greeting'))
    else:
        # we received input an the current state, so we can now exit it and
        # transition to a new state
        return str(exit_state(state))
```

And here is the code from my wsgi file

```
import sys

path = '/home/sapperpe/tree'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
project_folder = os.path.expanduser(path)
load_dotenv(os.path.join(project_folder, '.env'))

from tree import app as application
```

Currently, I'm getting this error when running in a bash server... not sure how else to check for errors since nothing is coming up in the error logs for this particular issues:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sapperpe/tree/tree.py", line 7, in <module>
    account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'
```

Comment: Judging from the error alone, it seems you haven't set a environment variable. Have you set your `os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']` environment variable (credentials) correctly?

Comment: Yes, I believe I've set up the environment variables correctly.